# Converting varbinary to longblob in MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob

We are storing data in an Innodb table having `varbinary` column. However, our data size requirement has grown to over 1 MB and hence I converted the column to `longblob`.

```
alter table mytable modify column d longblob;
```

Everything seems to be working as expected after I converted the column. However, I like to know from people who have done it earlier if anything more is required other than just converting column as shown above, especially

- is there any MySQL / MariaDB version specific issues with `longblob` that I should take care of. There is no index on the column.
- We use mysqldump to take regular backup. Do we need to change anything since the `blob` storage mechanism seems to be different than `varbinary`.
- Any other precautions/suggestion.

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: "NO" for all 3 questions. Except the indexing - indexed prefix length specifying is optional for VARBINARY and compulsory for LONGBLOB.

Comment: Thank you.  We only use it for storing binary data and not searching and hence there is no index on the column.

Comment: If so then you'll see no any difference. Moreover it is possible that you'll improve. But I'd recommend you to execute OPTIMIZE TABLE after changing the structure (be aware, this may be long process, and the table will be locked during it).

Comment: that's a good input. Will the improvement in terms of performance?

Comment: Moving the column from main table's body to external storage makes the table body more compact which may improve the performance, especially when the table scanning is used.